# ArcGIS Pro Dashboard export list

Tags: arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

I've created a list element in my ArcGIS Portal Dashboard. Is there a way for a user to export that list as a .csv or .xlsx?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro doesn't have dashboards, presume you mean ArcGIS Online/Portal.  See https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/latest/create-and-share/download-data.htm

Comment: Yes, sorry it is portal. I'll update my question.